# find a matrix given its column space (range)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given a Matrix C, I want to find a matrix N such that **Ima(N)=Ker(C)**.  I can calculate the null space of C and also I know N is not uniquely defined. So basicly I want to find a Matrix N based on the span for its range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find a basis of Kernel of $C = \{ c_1, \ldots, c_k\}$.
- Let $N=\begin{bmatrix}c_1 & \ldots & c_k \end{bmatrix}$.
- Find the image set of  $N$ above.

Answer (score 0):

Given a map $C:V \to W$, the $\ker(C)$ is a vector subspace of $V$, so all we need to do is let $N^{\prime}:V \to V/\ker(C)$  given by $v \mapsto v+\ker(C)$, and take $I-N^{\prime}=N$, which will project onto the kernel of $C$.

In the presence of a basis, extend $\ker(C)$ to a basis of $W$, and form the projection by taking identity on the basis and $0$ otherwise.

This is just one example, although the basic idea you are looking for can be summarized by the data of a [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence)